# Replace several character in a string

Tags: java, string, replace

I want to create a small program where I can enter a string using a scanner, and replace characters. For example, every "a" in the string should be replaced with a "4".

I have this sourcecode:

```
Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
String string = s.nextLine();
System.out.println("Your old text:" + original_string);

string.replace("i", "1");      
string.replace("a", "4");
System.out.println("Your new super awesome text: " + string);
```

For example, if I input "ia", it should return "14". Unfortunately, this does not happen.

Answer (score 5):

`String.replace` doesn't modify the original `String`. Indeed, `String`s *can't* be modified - all that can happen is that something creates a slightly different `String` and returns it.

```
string = string.replace("i", "1");
string = string.replace("a", "4");
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to reassign the value of the string to the replaced string.